# AST tree in antlr. Can I add a state object to it?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Right now, we have code that translates from one AST tree to their own tree.  I would prefer to get rid of this second tree(it is hard enough to understand one tree, let alone two when you join a project as trees are complex as it is).  One of the reasons for this is stuff was looked up on the tree walk.

I am wondering instead if during the tree walk, I could somehow add state to CommonTree that has the lookup information?

What I would like to see is something like this

```
CommonTree tree = parent.getChildren().get(0);
tree.setState(myMapOrObjectState);
```

This allows me to attach state to some nodes where it is needed before I pass to plugins.  Right now, I have this ugly recreate the whole tree and wrrap the AST tree :(.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to do (asking for). Can you elaborate (a bit)?

Comment: In your previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364723/antlr-is-there-any-way-to-generate-the-visitor-codegeneric-visitor, I answered how you can use your own AST. When doing so, you can use this custom AST to set a state during parsing.

Comment: godd point, I didn't go down that route yet, lots to learning still to do I guess